# How to group list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists looking like this:

```
['user1', time, cpus, mem]  
['user1', time, cpus, mem]
['user2', time, cpus, mem]
['user3', time, cpus, mem]
```

and so on..

I need just one list per user with time, cpus and mem added together. I've tried a few things but i cant make it work.

Comment: Please elaborate more. Are you trying to remove duplicates, sum up the relevant fields for a user? How do you want to handle the data

Comment: Use a `dict` with users as keys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a `dictionary` in order to group list items by `user`.

Then just use `zip` function to find out the sum for every feature from `time, cpus, mem` list.

```
mylist = [['user1', 1, 6, 8], 
['user1', 2, 7, 9],
['user2', 3, 7, 5],
['user3', 4, 7, 3]]

dict = {}
for elem in mylist:
  if elem[0] not in dict:
    dict[elem[0]] = []
  dict[elem[0]].append(elem[1:])

for key in dict:
  dict[key] = [sum(i) for i in zip(*dict[key])]
```

Output

```
In[1]: dict
Out[1]: {'user1': [3, 13, 17], 'user2': [3, 7, 5], 'user3': [4, 7, 3]}
```

Comment: Note that you should not use `dict` as a variable name since it is a built-in function https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html .

Answer (score 6):

A sweet, Pythonic and concise way to do that would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [                  
    ['user1', 0, 1, 0],                                                    
    ['user2', 2, 2, 2],      
    ['user3', 2, 2, 1],
    ['user3', 1, 1, 2],
    ['user1', 1, 0, 1],
]


merged = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0, 0])

for user, *values in l:               
     merged[user] = [sum(i) for i in zip(values, merged[user])]
```

Output:

```
In : merged
Out: 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
        {'user1': [1, 1, 1], 'user2': [2, 2, 2], 'user3': [3, 3, 3]})
```

That uses a `defaultdict` with a `list` of length 3 as its default value. The relevant user's values are updated for each element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

What about putting the list of lists into a `pandas.DataFrame`.
Then you could do grouping by users and apply aggregate functions like `sum()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['users'] = ['user1', 'user1','user2', 'user3']
df['time'] = [1,2,3,4]
df['mem'] = [128, 256, 1024, 2048]
df['cpu'] = [4, 2, 16, 32]

In: df
out: 
       users  time  cpu   mem
0  user1     1    4   128
1  user1     2    2   256
2  user2     3   16  1024
3  user3     4   32  2048

In: df.groupby('users').sum()
Out:
       time  cpu   mem
users                 
user1     3    6   384
user2     3   16  1024
user3     4   32  2048
```

Comment: Agreed - but why? Because of not wanting to use it or because of not knowing about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def gropulistsinlist(data,columns):
    ll=[[]]
    #ll.append([[3,4,5,6,7,7]])
    #columns=[4,5]
    #data=[[3,4,5,6,7,8],[3,4,5,6,7,7],[3,4,5,6,7,9],[3,4,5,6,7,8]]
    #data=[[3,4,5,6,7,7],[3,4,5,6,7,8],[3,4,5,6,7,7],[3,4,5,6,7,9],[3,4,5,6,7,8]]
    for d in data:
        addnew=0
        addwhat=0
        addwhere=0
        for index,l in enumerate(ll):
            if len(l)and([l[0][ii] for ii in columns]== [d[iii] for iii in columns]):
                addwhere=index
                addwhat=d
                addnew=0
                #print(ll)
                #print()
                break
            addnew=1
            addwhat=d
        if(addnew):
            ll.append([addwhat])
        else:
            ll[index].append(addwhat)
   ll.pop(0)
   return ll
```

ll will be

```
[
 [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]],
 [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]],
 [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]]]
```